# Removing console window for Glut/FreeGlut/GLFW?

Tags: c++, configuration, glut, freeglut, glfw

Under Visual C++, I have played around with Glut/FreeGlut/GLFW. It seems that everyone of these projects adds a CMD window by default. I tried removing it going under:

> Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor
>   Definitions

From here, I remove the _CONSOLE and replace it with _WINDOWS

Then I went under:

> Properties->Linker->System->SubSystem

And I set the option to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)

Then when I try compiling under GLFW, I get the following building errors:

- Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved
  external symbol _WinMain@16
  MSVCRT.lib
- Error 2 fatal error LNK1120: 1
  unresolved externals glfwWindow.exe

Is it possible to remove the console window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-console Windows applications use the `WinMain()` entry point convention. Your Glut examples probably use the standard C `main()` convention.

If you want a quick fix just for the demo app, the WinAPI function `FreeConsole()` might help.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683150(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This worked, and I will keep note of it for sure, but it would be nice to have an x-platform way of doing this. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, you don't really have the same problem on other platforms, so I'd suggest just wrapping FreeConsole() in an #ifdef WIN32 / #endif block.

Comment: Are you saying that in Linux and Mac, they do not have a console window by default?

Comment: I don't know about Mac. On Linux, if you launch an application from, for example, the Ubuntu desktop, a console window will *not* pop up to show you standard output. Program output will just disappear into nowhere. If you run it in a terminal, then it will dump standard output there like normal. There's no Linux equivalent for FreeConsole().

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will do what Sean Edwards wrote in the comment and add the #ifdef WIN32. This should do it.

Comment: It's worth noting that with `FreeConsole()`, the console window still pops up for an instant before disappearing.

Answer (score 22):

Under the linker options, set your entry point to **mainCRTStartup** . This function does the necessary setup of the MS libc and then calls main.

Comment: Works like a charm combined with @Emre's answer. Thanks.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

Answer (score 13):

My project just has a `main`, (no `WinMain`) and to disable console, I just set Linker->System->SubSystem to "`Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)`" instead of "`Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`" and the console goes away.

You don't need to mess with the Preprocessor Definitions to remove the console window.

I know my answer is a few years late, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this, but in VS2015 it gives a linker error: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)"

Comment: To get remove linker error: unresolved external symbol WinMain... you have to add 'mainCRTStartup' entry point: Linker->All Options->Entry Point (VS2019 Community)

Answer (score 12):

Most linkers support options that automatically remove the console startup code.

I think on GCC it's called -mwindows

Comment: +1 since i had WinMain, but the console kept opening.

Answer (score 7):

To get rid of the console using cmake, the link flags can be set as follows:

```
set_target_properties(exe_name PROPERTIES 
    LINK_FLAGS "/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
```

Comment: this is great wrapping into a IF (WIN32) to make an application cross platform.

Comment: Under Visual Studio, it works in Linker->All Options

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a `WinMain` entry point and copy your existing code (from `main`):

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  __in  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  __in  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  __in  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  __in  int nCmdShow
){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, but I would need a cross platform method of doing this. I'll probably have to go with what onteria_ said. I'll give that a shot. Thanks for the great answer though.

Comment: I use to have a WinMain to main converter. This way, your application provides both entry point. You just need to convert the command line from `lpCmdLine` to `argc`, `argv`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Is it something I have to supply to a function, or a flag for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new project as a console application, it will always run as such. You have to create a new GUI project if you want to run it in an actual window, otherwise the correct headers and libraries will not be included.

Also the WinMain function that's required will be included for you in the resulting template files.

Answer (score 0):

When I've gotten an error like that I was able to fix it by entering that following text in the **linker**, section **Advance**, option **Entry Point** the following:

> main

Comment: That did solve the error warning, but not it crashed and brought me to atonexit.c

Comment: I'm surprised it worked at all. AFAIK that setting just refers to the name of the entrypoint method, but doesn't change the signature at all. You're basically calling ()(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) as ()(char**, int), which is almost certainly going to play hell with your call stack when that method returns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed instruction how to solve it under `Visual Studio` without rewriting your code:

1. Open project **Properties** window
2. Leave the **Debug** configuration as is, console is great for debugging
3. Under **Release** configuration go to **Linker->All Options**
4. Set **Entry Point** to **mainCRTStartup**
5. Set **SubSystem** to **Windows: /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS**
6. Hit **Apply** to save setting

Now when you compile your project under `Debug` configuration, the console window appears, while under `Release` configuration it never opens. You can use the entry point function in any common forms:

```
int main() {}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {}
```

I personally prefer the second. Thanks to [Chao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46797458/11495894) and [elmindreda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239107/11495894), I upvoted you guys!